# Java SSH clinet using jcabi facing a FileNoFoundException

Tags: java, ssh, jcabi

I'm trying to use the jcabi library in order to ssh-connect a java application to a remote ubuntu server.

I'm using the following code sample

```
String host = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
String user = "myuser";
String key = "C:\path\to\the\pem\folder\relevantFile.pem"
String pwd = new Shell.Plain(
                new Ssh(host, 22,
                        user, key
                )
        ).exec("pwd");
System.out.println(hello);
```

When trying to run the code (it is in a @Test class BTW) I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\....\AppData\Local\Temp\jcabi-ssh201869605540056323.key (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

I also tried to set in the `key`, the *content* of the `pem` file, but the exception is the same.

Comment: As I see in the jcabi documentation the `key` parameter should be the content of your public key file and not the path of it. Read the file into a string and pass this as the key parameter.

Comment: I have the same error also when reading the content of the file into a string and passing it as the key parameter

Comment: You still have `FileNotFoundException`? If you use windows paths in Java code always use '\\' as path separator instead of single '\' so something like `"C:\\path\\to\\the\\pem\\folder\\relevantFile.pem"`.